# Como alterar o background das postagens no wordpress e deixar cada um com uma cor diferentes?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Olá, estou tendo um problema. Estou tentando fazer com que cada postagem tenha uma cor de background diferente. 
Tentei usar esse código abaixo no css mas ele deixa todas os posts de uma cor só.

```
div.postagem > div:nth-child(1) {
    background: #edc333;
}

div.postagem > div:nth-child(2) {
    background: #000;
}

div.postagem > div:nth-child(3){
    background: #3e4095;
}
```

Esse é o código que tenho na minha área de postagens:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<div class="col-md-4"><div class="postagem">

<div class="postagem-imagem">
<?php
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    the_post_thumbnail( 'miniatura' );
} ?></div> 

<div class="titulo"> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <?php the_title(); ?></a></div>

</div></div>


<?php endwhile?>
<?php else: ?>
<h2>Nada Encontrado</h2><?php endif; ?>
```

Esse é o código que tenho no css.

```
.postagem {
    height: 340px;
    overflow: hidden;

}
.postagem img {
    opacity: 0.2;
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
}

.postagem-imagem img {
    opacity: 0.3;
}

.titulo {
    font-size: 17.473px;
    font-family: "Arial";
    color: rgb(254, 255, 254);
    font-weight: 900;
    padding: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 1.2;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 111;
    top: 45px;

}

.titulo a {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Alguém poderia ajudar? Agradeço desde já!

Comment: o seu CSS está a ser carregado depois do css do theme?

Comment: @LuísAlmeida O meu theme só tem apenas 1 css que é onde está tudo.

Comment: tal como o nome css indica, os estilos funcionam por cascade... verifique se a última class que esta a ser aplicada é a sua...

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que a div `.postagem` é filha única da div `.col-md-4`, então o CSS `:nth-child(2)` e `:nth-child(3)` não se aplicam. Se mudares a class `.postagem` para a  onde já está a class `.col-md-4` deve resolver.

Para o teu caso, o seguinte irá funcionar, pois as `div.col-md-4` é que são *irmãs*, sendo que é possível focar em diferentes usando o `:nth-child`, ve abaixo o exemplo.

```css
.container {
  margin: 20px;
}

.postagem {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}

.col-md-4:nth-child(1) > .postagem {
  background: #edc333;
}

.col-md-4:nth-child(2) > .postagem {
  background: #000;
}

.col-md-4:nth-child(3) > .postagem {
  background: #3e4095;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="postagem">1 de 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="postagem">2 de 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="postagem">3 de 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

E [também no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/194512/)

Comment: Fiz assim, como voce disse:

 div.col-md-4 > div:nth-child(1){
    background: #000000;
}
div.col-md-4 > div:nth-child(2){
    background: #de5a5a;
}
div.col-md-4 > div:nth-child(3){
    background: #4c97bf;
}

Mas então a cor de TODAS ficaram preta. Parece que só entendeu o nth-child(1) e é como se não existisse o nth-child(2) e nth-child(3). Voce sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: Actualizei a resposta com mais informação. Esqueci que isto não notifica quem postou a pergunta, dai estar a comentar agora. Espero que ainda seja útil.